# Trying to implement an ajax pagination

Tags: django, scroll, pagination, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement pagination into my project but for some reasons beyond my comprehension, when i scroll down to the bottom, it does not load more content. Im thinking the issue could be in the javascript attached to the list.html below but I still dont know where exactly to fix.

Kindly point me to right direction

My code:

```
def user_list(request):
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    paginator = Paginator(users, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        if request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponse('')
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    if request.is_ajax():
        return render(request, 'account/user/list_ajax', {'section':         'people', 'users': users} )



return render(request, 'account/user/list.html', {'section': 'people', 'users': users})

list_ajax.html

{% load thumbnail %}
{% for user in users %}
<div class="people">
<a href="{{ user.get_absolute_url }}">
{% thumbnail user.profile.photo "180x180" crop="100%" as im %}
<a href="{{ user.get_absolute_url }}">
<img src="{{ im.url }}">
</a>
{% endthumbnail %}
</a>
<div class="info">
<a href="{{ user.get_absolute_url }}" class="title">
{{ user.username }}
</a>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}


list.html

{% block content %}
<h1>People</h1>
<div id="user-list">
    {% include "account/user/list_ajax.html" %}
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block domready %}
var page = 1;
var empty_page = false;
var block_request = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
var margin = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200;
if ($(window).scrollTop() > margin && empty_page == false &&
block_request == false) {
block_request = true;
page += 1;
$.get('?page=' + page, function(data) {
if(data == '') {
empty_page = true;
}
else {
block_request = false;
$('#user-list').append(data);
}
});
}
});
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you get  page = request.GET.get('page')

you need to import this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
```

and return thedata using JsonResponse:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    return JsonResponse(data)
```